Approximating curves using only line sections and arcs
Given a curve $C$, I need to construct another curve $C'$ approximating $C$ under the following constraints: (1) $C'$ needs to be smooth, (2) $C'$ is composed of only line sections and arcs, (3) $C'$ is sufficiently close to $C$. How to design such approximation algorithm to construct $C'$? Is there any existing literature that I can look into?

(i) What is a "line section"? (ii) What exactly do you mean by "smooth"? How can a curve be smooth and composed of only "line sections" and arcs (so as to contain at least one "line section" and at least one arc?

We can speak about an algorithm only if the given data is of combinatorial nature. However we can always approximate the curve by a piecewise linear curve (by choosing the set of breaking points to be a sufficiently dense subset of the given curve) and then smooth out the corners by sufficiently small arcs.
